# Asp.net mvc4 Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: model

how to fix Object reference not set to an instance of an object mvc4
I am receiving null id, In my DB my id is not null
please i need help

I have used the breakpoints and its receiving the null id at the following code:-
[image]

Comment: You've either passed the model as a null or the Id has not been populated (what type is it)? We'd need to see how the model is populated to help much more - please though post your code not screen shots in questions. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. I got it right by passing it value directly from table.